# issues while connecting to RDS-aurora-mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a RDS-Aurora(Mysql) database and I want to create tables inside this DB.

**MyRequirment:**
I want to create tables inside RDS db using python.

I found one python-library to do this task:`PyMySQL`. `PyMySQL` helped me to create a table inside the RDS-DB.

if my RDS-DB is accessibly publicly, i can use `PYMYSQL` to connect to DB and create tables.

**ISSUE**
My RDS-db is not `publicly accessiable`

How Can i connect to DB and create a table inside the RDS?

Answer (score 0):

> How Can i connect to DB and create a table inside the RDS?

There are three generally used solutions for that:

1. Run your code from an **instance** in the same VPC as your private RDS.
2. Use [VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html) (or Direct Connect if you have) to setup a connection between your home/work network and the VPC.
3. Use **ssh tunnel** for ad-hoc connections between home/work workstation and the private RDS. For that you would need to have some jump host in a public subnet through which you can setup the tunnel.

The ssh tunnel is the **easiest** to setup and use for development and testing purposes. There are many tutorials explaining how to set it up:

- [How can I use an SSH tunnel and MySQL Workbench to connect to a private Amazon RDS MySQL DB instance that uses a public EC2 instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-ssh-workbench-connect-ec2/)
- [How can I connect to my Amazon RDS DB instance using a bastion host from my Linux/macOS machine?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-using-bastion-host-linux/)
- [Connecting to an AWS RDS database through an SSH tunnel](https://help.data.world/hc/en-us/articles/360042882294-Connecting-to-an-AWS-RDS-database-through-an-SSH-tunnel)